# Is pointer substract behavior well-defined if operand point to data member of object but within the whole array boundary?

Tags: c

```
struct Item {
    int i;
    char * x;
};
Item all[] = { {0, "0"},  {1, "1"},  {2, "2"}, };

int i = all - (Item *) &all[2].x ;
printf("i = %d\n", i);
```

in the above code, I cast `&all[2].x`  to `(Item*)` and perform a pointer substract operation, 
mingw g++(4.6.1) produces `-2`,  and  VC2010 produces `-3`.

Is such operation a well-defined behavior (then VC likely has a  bug, anyway the distance between the two pointer is 2 elements) or not?

I've search the ANSI C standard(C99) 6.5.6  Semantics(9) says:

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements.

It's not very clear(what 'shall' imply) whether pointing to data member of the object is also ok.

I've also checked with <> Section 7.6.2 Additive operatives/Substraction, which says:

> ... The result is well defined and portable only if
>   the two pointers point to objects in the same array or point to one past the last object of the
>   array.

Looks like the pointer must point to the object itself, point to data member of the object is not well-defined. But the statement does not declare it explicitly.

There's [another resource](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) which says:

> ```
>  ( p2 - p1 ) == ( addr( p2 ) - addr( p1 ) ) / sizeof( T )
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `p2` and `p1` need not point to valid elements in an array. The formula above still works even when `p2` and `p1` contain invalid addresses (because they contain some address).

Which confuse me further.

Anyone please clarify this subtle issue?

Comment: Without a `typedef`, in C, `Item` is not defined (`struct Item` is defined though). Are you sure you are using a C compiler?

Comment: @pmg, he says he is using g++

Comment: Ah! Indeed, good thing I didn't try to fish out the relevant passage from the C Standard ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you have quoted from the standard is clear:

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object...

`&all[2].x` does *not* point to an element of the array `all`.  Pointing at a subobject of an element is not pointing at an element.

This means that the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast the address of `x` to `Item *`, because it doesn't point to the beginning of an `Item` (there's another member before it).

You *could* cast the address of the `i` member to `Item *`.

Answer (score 1):

```
----iiiippppiiiippppiiiipppp----
    \------/\------/\------/
     all[0]  all[1]  all[2]

                        |                  &all[2].x
    |       |       |       |           <= &all[0], [1], [2], [3]
```

There is no match between `&all[2].x` and any of `&all[??]`.

Comment: Thanks for both of your quick response, I know I should NOT cast the address, it is deliberately written in such a way, the origin author want to get the distance of two object even one of the pointer does not point to the object boundary.
I just want to know whether it's well-defined, or implementation-defined, or undefined/unspecified?